# How to evaluate $ \int_0^1 {\log x \log(1-x) \log^2(1+x) \over x} \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Solve that the following integral:
$$ \int_0^1 {\log x \log(1-x) \log^2(1+x) \over x} \,dx. $$

I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: The is a *definite* integral, which has a numerical value, so in that sense, yes it is possible to express it in closed form, albeit depending on what you mean by closed form.

Comment: $0.1099416891.$

Comment: Notice that the integrand is undefined at $x=0$ and $x=1$ or at any $x$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: $$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find my solution [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic225-10.html#p1569).

My argument here is greatly simplified by the use of complex analysis, thanks to the user [Random Variable](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic225-20.html#p1578). So you may also want to check it, too.

Comment: Extremely impressive.  Seriously, not enough adjectives to express how insanely great this solution is.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you for your praise! I was just lucky enough to find out that I can put things together...

Comment: Perhaps you should repost here in full.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I've already seen a solution of true wonders. I've posted the question after several failures of trying to solve it in my own way. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Wow. That is magnificent. Absolute masterpiece. Agree 100% with the people who suggest publishing. I've seen many, many papers in high ranking journals with far lesser quality.

Comment: You are extremely efficient.